# How do I use swagger-codegen cli with custom template?

Tags: swagger-codegen

I would like to add a few tweaks to the [typescript-fetch template](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/typescript-fetch).

I have downloaded the typescript-fetch folder linked above and stored it in `.\template` folder in my project. I assumed that all I would have to do is pass `--template-dir .\template` to the CLI as follows:

```
>Java -jar .\bin\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -l typescript-fetch -i https://localhost:7113/swagger/v1/swagger.json -o output -Dio.swagger.v3.parser.util.RemoteUrl.trustAll=true --template-dir .\template
```

but getting the following exception:

```
07:55:44.212 [Thread-1] INFO  i.s.codegen.v3.AbstractGenerator - writing file c:\projects\trustwell-api-client-ts\output\index.ts
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate supporting file 'SupportingFile:
        templateFile: api.mustache
        folder:
        destinationFilename: api.ts
'
        at io.swagger.codegen.v3.DefaultGenerator.generateSupportingFiles(DefaultGenerator.java:666)
        at io.swagger.codegen.v3.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:789)
        at io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:388)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: c:\projects\trustwell-api-client-ts\.\template\api.mustache:142:73: found: '-last', expected: 'no viable alternative at input '{{^-last''
                                        ? configuration.accessToken("{{name}}", [{{#scopes}}"{{{scope}}}"{{^-last}}, {{/-last}}{{/scopes}}])
                                                                         ^
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.HbsErrorReporter.syntaxError(HbsErrorReporter.java:93)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.antlr.ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError(ProxyErrorListener.java:41)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.antlr.Parser.notifyErrorListeners(Parser.java:544)
...
```

It seems that CLI is picking up my folder, but I'm not sure if there is anything else I need to do to make this work.

**Question:** how can I run swagger-codegen CLI with local mustache templates?

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to use templates from here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/tree/master/src/main/resources/handlebars/typescript-fetch

I don't understand the distinction, and I suspect the two might get out of sync at some point, but it works.